# Line integral around singular point (Residue theorem)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

We have function $\frac{1}{x-\frac{i}{2}}$ which has one singular point $x=\frac{i}{2}$ so if we integrate around it we get by [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) $2 \pi i$.

```
Integrate[1/(x-I/2),{x,-1,1,1+I,-1+I,-1}]
(* 2 Pi I *)
```

I constructed the rectangular path `{x,-1,1,1+I,-1+I,-1}` manually.

Now I want to do the same integral but instead use a circle path.

I tried:

```
Integrate[1/((a+I b)-I/2),{a,b}\[Element]Circle[{0,1/2},1]]
(* 0 *)
```

But it seems it is not a circle around the singular point as the result is `0`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks to me that you'd need to do it manually for now: `Integrate[(1/(z - I/2) /. z -> I/2 + Exp[I t]) D[I/2 + Exp[I t], t], {t, 0, 2 π}]`

Comment: That is more work than with a rectangular path. I hoped for something like "I provide center of a circle in complex plane and its radius then compute me the integral".

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
f[z_] := 1/(z - I/2)
intF[f_, c_, r_] := 
 NIntegrate[(f[z] /. z -> c + r Exp[I t]) I r Exp[I t], {t, -Pi, Pi}]
intF[f, I/2, 1/2]
```

(* 0. + 6.28319 I *)

Comment: Yes, that is what J. M. suggested in his comment.